# Aframe Trigger Animation of Element through event-component & proxy-component

Tags: animation, aframe, webvr

I'm trying to trigger animations on other elements while a certain element is being looked at. So what I'm trying to achieve is: When I hover the ball, the text should fade in. And when I leave the ball, the text should fade out.

I was told this should be possible with the `aframe-proxy-event-component` but I couldn't find any example or documentation on how to use this.

The code looks something like that:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-animation-component@5.1.2/dist/aframe-animation-component.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-event-set-component@4.0.0/dist/aframe-event-set-component.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-proxy-event-component/dist/aframe-proxy-event-component.min.js"></script>

<a-mixin id="scaleUpMixin" animation__scale="property: scale; dur: 500; easing: easeInOutQuad; to: 1.5 1.5 1.5;"></a-mixin>
<a-mixin id="scaleDownMixin" animation__scale2="property: scale; dur: 500; easing: easeInOutQuad; to: 1 1 1;"></a-mixin>

<a-mixin id="fadeInText" animation__opacity="property: text.opacity; dur: 500; to: 1"></a-mixin>
<a-mixin id="fadeOutText" animation__opacity2="property: text.opacity; dur: 500; to: 0"></a-mixin>

<a-entity rotation="0 -10 0">
    <!-- Planet -->
    <a-sphere color="yellow" position="0 1.8 -5" radius="0.5" scale="1 1 1" 
        mixin="scaleUpMixin scaleDownMixin"
        animation__scale="startEvents: mouseenter;"
        animation__scale2="startEvents: mouseleave;">
    </a-sphere>

    <!-- Text -->
    <a-text id="TextMercury" class="textbox" text="value: Merkur; align: center; color:#FFF" opacity="0" scale="0.8 0.8 0.8"
        position="0 1.8 -1"> </a-text>

</a-entity>
```

Here's a live demo: https://gorgeous-badge.glitch.me/

An the code: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/gorgeous-badge?path=index.html:30:61

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach the `proxy-event` component to the sphere. Its quite well documented (with an example) @[github](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/proxy-event)

If you have a button, you can redirect any event like this:

```
<a-box proxy-event="event: event; to: targetSelector; as: newname"></a-box>
<a-entity animation="(...) startEvents: newname"></a-entity>
```

Check it out in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ec1bdvk0/1/).